# I am trying to fill all NaN values in rows with number data types to zero in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a DateFrame with a mixture of string, and float rows.  The float rows are all still whole numbers and were only changed to floats because their were missing values.  I want to fill in all the NaN rows that are numbers with zero while leaving the NaN in columns that are strings.  Here is what I have currently.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float']).fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

This doesn't work and I think it is because .select_dtypes() returns a view of the DataFrame so the .fillna() doesn't work.  Is there a method similar to this to fill all the NaNs on only the float rows.

Comment: Can u post part of ur dataframe or text you imported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either `DF.combine_first` (does not act `inplace`):

```
df.combine_first(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).fillna(0))
```

or `DF.update` (modifies `inplace`):

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).fillna(0))
```

The reason why `fillna` fails is because `DF.select_dtypes` returns a completely new dataframe which although forms a subset of the original `DF`, but is not really a part of it. It behaves as a completely new entity in itself. So any modifications done to it will not affect the `DF` it gets derived from.

Note that `np.number` selects all numeric type.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured your subset theory was correct but you explained it much better.  I looked at the documentation but I am still a little unclear, what exactly is .update() used for?

Comment: Both `combine_first` & `update` function almost alike. Only difference is that the former patches values for matching indices from the right `DF` into the left `DF` in case of *missing values* in the left `DF` whereas the latter alters *finite vaues* from the right `DF` into the left one. See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns for a working example showing their difference.

Comment: Those examples really helped.  You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your `pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes` approach is good; you've just got to cross the finish line:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 'string', 'string', 'more string'], 'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4], 'C': [4, np.nan, 5, 6]})
>>> df
             A    B    C
0          NaN  NaN  4.0
1       string  NaN  NaN
2       string  3.0  5.0
3  more string  4.0  6.0
```

Don't try to perform the in-place `fillna` here (there's a time and place for `inplace=True`, but here is not one). You're right in that what's returned by `select_dtypes` is basically a view. Create a new dataframe called `filled` and join the filled (or "fixed") columns back with your original data:

```
>>> filled = df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float']).fillna(0)
>>> filled
     B    C
0  0.0  4.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  3.0  5.0
3  4.0  6.0
>>> df = df.join(filled, rsuffix='_filled')
>>> df
             A    B    C  B_filled  C_filled
0          NaN  NaN  4.0       0.0       4.0
1       string  NaN  NaN       0.0       0.0
2       string  3.0  5.0       3.0       5.0
3  more string  4.0  6.0       4.0       6.0
```

Then you can drop whatever original columns you had to keep only the "filled" ones:

```
>>> df.drop([x[:x.find('_filled')] for x in df.columns if '_filled' in x], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df
             A  B_filled  C_filled
0          NaN       0.0       4.0
1       string       0.0       0.0
2       string       3.0       5.0
3  more string       4.0       6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a dataframe like this

```
    col1    col2    col3    id
0   1       1       1       a
1   0       NaN     1       a
2   NaN     1       1       NaN
3   1       0       1       b
```

You can select the numeric columns and fillna

```
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
df[num_cols]=df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).fillna(0)


    col1    col2    col3    id
0   1       1       1       a
1   0       0       1       a
2   0       1       1       NaN
3   1       0       1       b
```